# Android Studio recording/capture screen doesn't work

Tags: android-studio

2 weeks ago it was working, now it doesn't work. The device connected to adb has android 4.4 kitkat. After setting resolution, click start recording and then it pops up the save as window so nothing was recorded. Any suggestions?
This is the error: `Unexpected error while copying video recording from device: Remote object doesn't exist!`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by selecting unsupported resolution (width/height). You can determine the max width/height by running the screenrecord command from the adb shell.

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/test.mp4
```

This command will print the supported resolution, for example:

```
The max width/height supported by codec is 1280x720
```

Comment: Not working. Now it is saying that the file location is not accessible courtesy to Android M.

Comment: Just change the file location to a writable one. You probably do not have an SD card or you do not have write permissions.

Comment: `adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/test.mp4` returns:

Unable to get output buffers
Encoder failed (err=-38)

Comment: In my case I was trying to record the wrong device/emulator, I was trying to record a just disconnected device.